# Have i screwed up my rails console? I get verbose errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

When i type something like `person.valid?` in my rails console, instead of returning 'false' i get the following output:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `person' for main:Object
from (irb):7
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure if this is a feature i've accidentally enabled or if i've got something wrong with my install. If all of this output is not needed, how can i get rid of it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get `false` since you have no variable named `person` hence no method called `valid?` can be called on it. This is normal irb behaviour telling you you've done something wrong.

Comment: @jakub_hampl Cheers. I had typed in `Person.create` and then `person.valid?` when i should have typed `person = Person.create` first as per the instructions in the tutorial I am following.